# Change bullet values in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm aware of the Gmail shortcuts for adding numbered and object bullets. Is there a way to increase the number of a bullet? For example, if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to start a numbered list, then add bullets under the first item, the second main item is reset to 1.

Is there anyway to tell Gmail to "Continue Counting" like in Microsoft Word?

What I want:

1. Hardware store

   - Bug spray
   - Saw blade
2. Grocery store

   - Beer
   - more beer

What actually happens:

```
1. Hardware store
   - Bug spray
   - Saw blade

1. Liquor store
   - Beer
   - more beer
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The key is to indent the bulleted items so that they become a "sub-list" under the numbered list. If you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and convert it to a bulleted list, it becomes a new list, then when you go back to a numbered list it's treated as another new list.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut to indent. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is the shortcut for bulleted list.

Let me see if I can illustrate in steps.

### Step 1

Start your list

> 1. Hardware store
> 2. Bug spray

### Step 2

Indent the  item just created (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>)

> 1. Hardware store
>
>    1. Bug spray

### Step 3

Convert to a bulleted list (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>)

> 1. Hardware store
>
>    - Bug spray

### Step 4

Continue down to your next numbered item

> 1. Hardware store
>
>    - Bug spray
>    - Saw blade
>    - Grocery store

### Step 5

Outdent to make it part of the "super" list. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>)

> 1. Hardware store
>
>    - Bug spray
>    - Saw blade
> 2. Grocery store

Continue as necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to use a letter-ordered list (a, b, c, d) instead of a numbered list for a list nested under a parent numbered list?